# Как сделать активным только одно InfoWindow Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-api

Есть карта с маркерами, по клику отображаем InfoWindow. Проблема в том, что по умолчанию они отображаются до тех пор, пока пользователь сам не закроет окно. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при клике на карту или другой маркер, последнее InfoWindow закрывалось. Была попытка сделать это через id, которые передаются маркеру и через eventListener, но безуспешно. 
Маркер отображается так:

```
var gmInfo = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: template,
        pixelOffset : new google.maps.Size(-2, -17),
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng)
    });

    options.content = $('<div class="babuska-marker"></div>');
    options.containerOptions = {
        class: 'babuska-marker-wrapper'
    };

    options.onClick = function () {
        gmInfo.open(map);
    };

    new CustomLayer(new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng), map, options);
```